# limit google places API results

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am working Google places API and I am looking to return one result per API call, as opposed to the standard that come back with each call. An help is appreciated.

Ger

Comment: Please add part of the code you already have...

Comment: why there is a problem getting many places and then select first one? use `rankBy` parameter to choose between "best" match or "closest" location https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=ru#place_search_requests